# Problems with python environments and packages in a conda managed machine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, conda, mongoengine

I am trying to learn MongoEngine, MongoDB from a python Flask environment

I have a python 3.8 environment and when I issue

```
conda install -c blaze flask-mongoengine
```

I get an error:

> Specifications:
>
> - flask-mongoengine -> python[version='2.7.*|3.4.*']
>
> Your python: python=3.8

so I tried creating and activating a Python 3.4 environment:

```
conda create -n uav python=3.4 -c conda-forge
conda activate uav
(uav) bob@rja15 uav log % python --version
Python 3.4.5
(uav) bob@rja15 uav log % conda install -c blaze flask-mongoengine
```

but get a different error:

> Specifications:
>
> - flask-mongoengine -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
>
> Your python: python=3.4

I am lost. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me with conda 4.8.3 and [mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba) 0.4.3, Ubuntu 18.04.

I know nothing about flask-mongoengine but it seems the recipe [here](https://anaconda.org/blaze/flask-mongoengine) hasn't been updated for 5 years and it doesn't seem very popular.

```
conda create -n tmp-db
conda activate tmp-db
mamba install flask-mongoengine
mamba install -c blaze flask-mongoengine

conda list
# packages in environment at /home/dario/miniconda3/envs/tmp-db:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       1_gnu    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2020.10.14                    0  
certifi                   2017.1.23                py34_0    conda-forge
click                     7.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
flask                     1.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
flask-mongoengine         0.7.1                    py34_0    blaze
flask-wtf                 0.14.3                     py_0    conda-forge
itsdangerous              1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.11.2             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 9.3.0               h5dbcf3e_17    conda-forge
libgomp                   9.3.0               h5dbcf3e_17    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.0                      py34_0    conda-forge
mongoengine               0.16.3                     py_1    conda-forge
ncurses                   5.9                          10    conda-forge
openssl                   1.0.2u               h516909a_0    conda-forge
pip                       20.2.4                     py_0    conda-forge
pymongo                   3.2.2                    py34_0    conda-forge
python                    3.4.5                         2    conda-forge
readline                  6.2                           0    conda-forge
setuptools                32.3.1                   py34_0    conda-forge
six                       1.15.0             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.13.0                        1    conda-forge
tk                        8.5.19                        2    conda-forge
werkzeug                  1.0.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.35.1             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
wtforms                   2.3.3                      py_0  
xz                        5.2.5                h516909a_1    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h516909a_1010    conda-forge
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Meanwhile I also got the impression that this library is old and not actively mantained/used and will therefore probably switch to native pymongo.